# Detect any select that a user changes the value of

Tags: jquery

I have 20 selects on a page and I need to detect when a user sets any one of them to a value > 0 (the default value for each one is 0). They are all of class "numSel" so I'm trying to make this code work:

```
if($('.numSel').val() > 0){ 
    $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);           
}
```

But this only works on the first select on the page. If I choose one of the other selects the submit button remains disabled.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code is within a [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) or [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) block, you can use `this` to reference the `<select>` that changed.

```
$('.numSel').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() > 0)
        $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);
}).change(); // run the block here to detect the initial values
```

If you want it to revert to be disabled when all of the values are set back to `0`, add a `.each()` block to the `else` statement.

```
$(".numSel").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() > 0) {
        $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
        $(".numSel").each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() > 0) {
                $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
                return false; // exits the each loop
            }
        });
    }
}).change();
```

Comment: @charlietfl [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) returns a number when the value is a number.

Comment: Works great. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If the user changes all values back to zero, what happens?

Comment: @PeterKA The submit button will remain disabled. If they want it to revert, the `if` would need to be wrapped in a `.each()` block.

Answer (score 0):

Assign your selects with `unique ids` and `same classes`.

Let's say you assign their classes as `numSel`. And this is how you will detect all of them if they change.

```
function callbackFn() {
  var $sel = $(this);
  // $sel.attr('id');
  var val = parseInt($sel.val());
  if (val > 0) {
     $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);
  }
}

$('.numSel').on('change', callbackFn);
```

Answer (score 0):

This way, you are referring to the current select, and don't need to specify a specific selector:

```
$('.numSel').on('change', function() {
    if(parseInt($(this).val()) > 0) {
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', false); 
    }
});
```

Comment: The `parseInt` is unnecessary, and it's `#submit` which should be disabled.

Comment: Updated to #submit

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
 $('.numSel').each(function(){ 
 if(parseInt($(this).val())>0)
 //Your code           
 });
```

Explanation:
For each of the class numSel, check through the value if it is more than 0.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but I think what you are looking for is to allow submitting if any of the dropdowns is non-zero and always disable it if all of them are set to 0. If that's the case then this is what you need:

```
$('.numSel').on('change', function() {
    var isDisabled = true;
    $(this).each(function() {
        if(parseInt($(this).val()) > 0) {
            isDisabled = false;
        }
    });

    $(this).prop('disabled', isDisabled);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to detect when the user sets any of the 20 t0 a value > 0 **but not when the user sets any to 0**. Right? You can use the `change` event and some logic or you can use the `change` event and a own `custom event`:

```
$('.numSel').on('change', function() {
    //if value > 0 trigger 'custom_event'
    !+this.value || $(this).trigger('custom_event');
});

$('.numSel').on('custom_event', function() {
    //Do stuff (when custom_event is triggered)
});
```

```js
$('.numSel').on('change', function() {
    //if value > 0 trigger 'custom_event'
    !+this.value || $(this).trigger('custom_event');
});

$('.numSel').on('custom_event', function() {
    //Do stuff (when custom_event is triggered)
    console.log( this.value, this );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="numSel" name="one">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

<select class="numSel" name="two">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

<select class="numSel" name="three">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

**Warning**

**Detecting *when a user sets any one of them to a value > 0* is not a safe way of controlling the button**.
On any one change event, it is safer to actually count how many `select` elements have a non-zero value and determine what to do based on that number. You're not detecting when/if the user changes values on the detected select elements to zero. And now, here's the code:

```
$('.numSel').on('change', function() {
    //count number of non-zero values
    var n = $('.numSel').filter(function() {
        return +this.value > 0;
    }).length;
    //set button based on the number
    $('.submit').prop( 'disabled', n == 0 );
})
//for when the page loads
.first().change();
```

```js
$('.numSel').on('change', function() {
    //count number of non-zero values
    var n = $('.numSel').filter(function() {
        return +this.value > 0;
    }).length;
    //set button based on the number
    $('.submit').prop( 'disabled', n == 0 );
})
//for when the page loads
.first().change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="numSel" name="one">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

<select class="numSel" name="two">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

<select class="numSel" name="three">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

<button class="submit">SUBMIT</button>
```